# What is the best way to add seven days recursively to a date in ruby on rails 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, ruby-on-rails-5

I currently a create multiple bookings endpoint, this takes weeks as "qty" as a param.

So far I have this:

In my controller action:

```
     def multiple
          @qty = params[:qty]
          @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
          if @booking.save 
            @newbookings = @booking.createmore(@qty)
            render json: @newbookings, status: :created
          else 
            render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
      end
```

And in my model i have a routine to create multiple.

```
    def createmore(quantity)
        bookings = []
        quantity.to_i.times do 
            bookings.push(self)
        end 
        puts "#{@bookings}"
        newbookings = []
        firstBooking = self

        bookings.each do | booking |
            booking.start = firstBooking.start
            booking.end = firstBooking.end
            booking.name = firstBooking.name
            booking.email = firstBooking.email
            booking.contact = firstBooking.contact
            newbookings.push(booking)
        end
        newbookings.each do | booking |
            booking.save
        end
    end
```

The question is, how to add a week to the date recursively. i.e add 7 days to the second booking and 14 to the 3rd and 21 to the 4rth etc until qty is zero.

I can do this in JavaScript with moment but have no clue where to even start in ruby. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method from the Enumerable module together with the additions to the [time management extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-datetime-calculations-durations) included in Active Support. A simplified example would look like this:

```rb
bookings.each_with_index do |booking, i|
  booking.start = firstBooking.start + i.weeks
end
```

The index `i` starts from 0, so the first booking will keep the original start date (adding 0 weeks). The rest of the weeks will start `i` weeks later than the original one.

**EDIT**

As Scott points out, whenever one of the elements is updated, all of them are. The key here is that there is not an array with `n` objects that can be updated independently, there is an array with `n` references to the same object, so a change made to one of them applies to all of them.

Probably you want to `push` [a copy of the original object](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) every time instead of pushing the original element:

```rb
quantity.to_i.times do 
  bookings.push(self.dup)
end
```

By doing so, there will effectively be `n` copies of the original object and you will be able to update each one of them separately.

Comment: thanks for this, I tried it but it seems to add the last index to all the dates so instead of each index

Comment: Also I took the . out before do otherwise it spits a syntax error

Comment: I have updated the answer removing the typo and adding a way to solve the issue you mentioned